# How to run two functions in parallel in python ROS2

Tags: python, simulation, ros2, multi-agent, nav2

I am creating a simulation with two robots(using ROS2 Iron and on gazebo) who will play Capture the Flag game. I have a python API that sends them navigation tasks, however, the navigation tasks don't start at the same time. I want both of the robots to start navigating together.
This is an example of what I want to run:

```
navigator1.goThroughPoses(goal_pose1)  #Sends navigation command to one robot
navigator2.goThroughPoses(goal_pose2)  #Sends navigation command to the other robot
```

I basically want to run these two processes in parallel so that both the robots start navigation at the same time. Further context: I am using [Simple Commander API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html) to send navigation commands through the robot.

Edit: As of now I used the [API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html) present to write the code for sending `goThroughPoses` command via python. The purpose of using the API is to have better flexibility. I added namespace functionality to the API and created two objects each controlling one robot and having the ability to send navigation commands present in nav2 which run successfully.
However, as of now, one robot starts its navigation before the other one, and hence I want the functionality that both robots start their navigation simultaneously. I tried using the multiprocessing module as well as concurrent.futures, to the send command shown above, however, they don't seem to work. As of now, I am looking into MultiThreadedExecutors to ensure they start at the same time. At this stage, I am just researching my options and trying out different things to see what would work, and I felt a question here would narrow down my search to relevant libraries, APIs etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain a bit more about how you're doing it right now and what you've thought about or tried to do to make this happen. There are many ways to solve this problem. But without more context it's likely that any valid suggestion will require more work from you to implement than the actual fix due to different assumptions.

Comment: I apologize for making the question a bit ambiguous. I added things I have done till now and tried to provide more context. Let me know if you need any more information regarding this. Any guidance would be helpful, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Ensuring that two robots run at the same time is a very complicated problem. "at the same time" is often not necessarily clearly measurable. In general threading libraries are about allowing things to run in parallel, but not necessarily synchronously. You will need to be doing additional blocking and signaling to make thins synchronous.